# how to calculate histogram using every nth pixel opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I'm using this opencv function for calculate the histogram(For blue color).

```
calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
```

Here we use all pixels in the image for calculate the histogram. Assume that I need to calculate the histogram using every 10th pixel or 100th pixel. Is there an efficient way to do this? I need to do this because I think it may increase the performances in histogram calculation even though some details are lossed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not create another image ehich holds just the pixels you want?  And run calchist on that image?

Comment: @Gilad - I think it is affect to the performances of my algorithm. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: I agree with @Gilad, that'll probably be the best solution. Although I don't understand how the "performance of a histogram" would increase by using fewer samples.

Comment: @a-Jays I can't speak to this specific data set, but decreasing the number of pixels by an order of magnitude will certainly decrease the time it takes to calculate the histogram (remember you need to bin every pixel).  However, the act of removing or selecting the pixels to use might very well take as much compute time as just using them.

Comment: @denver - Agree with you.

Comment: @denver yes, `O(n)`, I know, I didn't mean the execution time anyway. By "performance of histogram", I assumed that the OP meant the operation which the histogram will be used for. Selecting fewer samples would lead to "coarser" histogram magnitudes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cv::resize()` with nearest-neighbor "interpolation" to sub-sample the image every 10th pixel along both axes. Then calculate the histogram on the sub-sampled image.

Beyond using an extra 1% memory (beyond your image), it should be as efficient as calculating the histogram on the fly.

Comment: I would expect doing interpolation would be far more expensive then doing the histogram with all pixels.

Comment: @denver: Nearest neighbor "interpolation" basically just samples every 10th pixel every 10 rows, for a total of 1/100th of the image pixels. There is no real interpolation here. It is just a single pass over 0.01 of the pixels. That is certainly cheaper than a full pass over all the pixels.

Comment: @AdiShavit Depends on implementation and the degree of under sampling being done.  While you are not calculating the output pixel value, you are still calculating which pixel to take (usually includes rounding and casting operations).  You still have the memory allocation and the copying of pixel values as well.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation time is linear with the number of pixels.  You essentially take each pixel once and put it into a bin.  Doing any transform on them ahead of time will result in undoing the time savings.

As such doing something like resizing or creating a new image will defeat the purpose.

The best way to realize any savings would be to role your own histogram calculation function that simply increased the index by (10, 100, or 1000) as you iterate over the pixels.  The histogram algorithm is very easy to re-write.  It is a typical homework problem for undergraduates.

I would think that in few situations it would be worth trying to save time by doing the histogram with fewer pixels.  You must be working with very tight time constraints or very large data.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Yes I'm working on a project which is analysing exiting events in football videos. In that case I'm generating  histograms for each and every frame in the video(64 bins). That means very large amount of data. So that I'll try to rewrite the histogram calculation algorithm as you instructed.